# How to perform encoding of a wave file into base64 encoding in AS3

Tags: flash, encoding, base64

I need to perform encoding of a wav file into base64...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mx.utils.Base64Encoder` (see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/Base64Encoder.html).
First you need to convert your wav into a `bytearray` and then use `Base64Encoder.encodeBytes()`.

Answer (score 0):

An even faster version here: http://www.sociodox.com/base64.html